# ¿Es posible cambiar la imagen del producto del carro dinamicamente woocommerce?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Me gustaría que a la hora de agregar un producto al carro pueda cambiar la imagen por una generada con variaciones al a original.

```html
function custom_new_product_image($cart_object) {
    $a = '<img src="/images/5ce6533fe1354.png" />';
    return $a;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'custom_new_product_image' );
```

con eso la cambio estaticamente pero yo quiero hacerlo dinamicamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo solucione con uso de session

```
function custom_new_product_image($cart_object){
   $ruta = $_SESSION["imageURL"];
   $a = '<img src="'.$ruta.'" />';
   return $a;
}
```

Para ello modifique el codigo de cart.php y en la columna de la imagen recorro mi array y antes de llamar a

```
$thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product- 
>get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

Almaceno en $_SESSION["imageURL"] la ruta de la imagen a poner.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a ver si en $cart_object tienes los id's de los productos que hay en el carrito, a partir de ahí ya tienes el id de cada producto para obtener las imágenes de sus variaciones, captura la url de la imagen que necesitas, la pones en el src de tu  y listo.